# How to extract a JSON variable from JSON Payload in Apigee?

Tags: apigee

The below `JSON` is served as a response-

```
{
  "result": {
    "status": "ERROR",
    "error": {
      "errorCode": "x500",
      "errorType": "string500",
      "errorMessage": "string700"
    }
  }
}
```

I am successfully able to extract the below variables-

```
<JSONPayload>
   <Variable name="result">
      <JSONPath>$.result</JSONPath>
   </Variable>
   <Variable name="status">
      <JSONPath>$.result.status</JSONPath>
   </Variable>
   <Variable name="errorCode">
      <JSONPath>$.result.error.errorCode</JSONPath>
   </Variable>
   <Variable name="errorType">
      <JSONPath>$.result.error.errorType</JSONPath>
   </Variable>
   <Variable name="errorMessage">
      <JSONPath>$.result.error.errorMessage</JSONPath>
   </Variable>
</JSONPayload>
```

However, when I try to extract the complete `error` object from within the `JSON` object, it shows **Failed to execute the ExtractVariables**

```
<Variable name="error">
   <JSONPath>$.result.error</JSONPath>
</Variable>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose a different name other than `error` as it is a reserved word in `Apigee` platform, and hence the failed message.